# Determain which Forms overlay Parent Form modally in WinForms

Tags: .net, vb.net, winforms

I'm trying to find out what forms blocks the parent modaly.

My Environment is a bit complex. I got an AppToolBar (like the Taskbar) which is the main form of the application. All Forms opend by my own toolbar are therefore

```
ShowInTaskbar = False
```

because there are shown in my own toolbar. Also all Forms opend by the application directly (via the AppToolBar) are stored in a List. Lets assume I have Form1, Form2 and Form3. Form1 and Form2 are directly opend by the AppToolBar, Form3 is created by Form1 and then shown by

```
Form3.ShowDialog(Form1)
```

At some point the user minimizes my whole application which then calls

```
Form1.Hide
Form2.Hide
```

I can't set the state of Form1 to minimized, as it would appear as a minimized window above the Taskbar because it isn't shown in the taskbar. Now Form1 should call Form3.Hide. So how can I find out, that Form3 blocks Form1 from the Form1 point of view?

Cheers.

Comment: Hiding a dialog will close it.  You can find back forms with the Application.OpenForms property and see who owns a form with the Owner property.

Comment: @HansPassant I didn't know, that hiding will close it. Thank you. I must minimize it then, but that is okay. Application.OpenForms is exactly what I was searching for. Would you like to create this as an answer? Then I could accept it as a solution.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Just for the sake of having this question marked answered and Hans not posting his solution, I will.

You'll get all open forms by calling

```
Application.OpenForms
```

which will give you back all Forms. To find out which form blocks Form1, you simply have to search for the *Owner* Property in all open Forms and return those forms where the *Owner* is Form1.